Data Not Displaying Correctly with PostgreSQL odbc_fdw
After connecting to Oracle and DB2 via odbc_fdw and retrieving data, the record count of the tables is displayed correctly, but the data for each record's fields is not displayed correctly.
The value of the first field is always '#', and the values of the fields from the second onwards are null.
[Reference Information]

The server-side versions are as follows:
OS: Windows Server 2019 Standard
PostgreSQL: postgresql-x64-16

The database character set on the PostgreSQL server side is UTF8
* It does not seem to be a character encoding issue.

The ODBC definition on the OS side is correct.
It can be referenced correctly with another tool (A5:SQL Mk-2).

I tried using the following two versions of the odbc_fdw module, but the result was the same:
  1.The Windows binary version (0.5.2.3) from the following site, CREATE EXTENSION odbc_fdw

       https://www.postgresonline.com/journal/index.php?/categories/85-odbc_fdw

       POSTGRESQL 16 64-BIT FOR WINDOWS FDWS

  2\. The build result of the source code from the following site (0.5.2.3), ALTER EXTENSION odbc_fdw UPDATE                  https://github.com/CartoDB/odbc_fdw


Status of other modules:
oracle_fdw : OK (Oracle seems usable, no issues with Japanese)

db2_fdw  :   NG (Only supports US English version of Windows?)

tds_fdw  :   NG (Not supported on Windows)

jdbc_fdw :   NG (Build attempt resulted in errors, possibly not supported on Windows?)



■Query Result: odbc_fdw (Oracle)
postgres=# select count(*) from odbc_zzzz_test_tbl4;
count
-------
      2
(1 row)

postgres=# select * from odbc_zzzz_test_tbl4;
 data_id | name1 | name2 | update_d
---------+-------+-------+----------
 #       |       |       |
 #       |       |       |
(2 rows)

■Query Result: odbc_fdw (DB2)
postgres=# select count(*) from odbc_yyyy_CONNHEADER_SCMDWH_EVENT;
 count
-------
  1263
(1 row)

postgres=# select * from odbc_yyyy_CONNHEADER_SCMDWH_EVENT;
 appl_id | appl_name | client_protocol
---------+-----------+-----------------
 #       |           |
 #       |           |
 #       |           |
 #       |           |
 (rest omitted)

■Definition: odbc_fdw (Oracle)
CREATE SERVER odbc_zzzz
FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER odbc_fdw
OPTIONS (dsn 'zzzz', encoding 'SJIS');

CREATE USER MAPPING FOR postgres
SERVER odbc_zzzz
OPTIONS (odbc_UID 'xxxx', odbc_PWD 'xxxx');

CREATE FOREIGN TABLE
  odbc_zzzz_test_tbl4 (
    DATA_ID text,
    NAME1 text,
    NAME2 text,
    UPDATE_D date
  )
  SERVER odbc_zzzz
  OPTIONS (
    sql_query 'select DATA_ID,NAME1,NAME2,UPDATE_D from ssss.test_tbl',
    sql_count 'select count(DATA_ID) from ssss.test_tbl'
  );

----------------------------------
* Oracle Table Definition

CREATE TABLE ssss.TEST_TBL
(
    DATA_ID                        VARCHAR2(8),
    NAME1                          VARCHAR2(10),
    NAME2                          VARCHAR2(50),
    UPDATE_D                       DATE
)
----------------------------------

■Definition: odbc_fdw (DB2)
CREATE SERVER odbc_yyyy 
FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER odbc_fdw 
OPTIONS (dsn 'yyyy', encoding 'SJIS');

CREATE USER MAPPING FOR postgres
SERVER odbc_yyyy
OPTIONS (odbc_UID 'xxxx', odbc_PWD 'xxxx');

CREATE FOREIGN TABLE
  odbc_yyyy_CONNHEADER_SCMDWH_EVENT (
    APPL_ID text,
    APPL_NAME text,
    CLIENT_PROTOCOL integer
  )
  SERVER odbc_yyyy
  OPTIONS (
    sql_query 'select APPL_ID,APPL_NAME,CLIENT_PROTOCOL from aaaa.bbbb_tbl',
    sql_count 'select count(APPL_ID) from aaaa.bbbb_tbl'
  );

What could be the problem?
Is there a specific solution?
Thank you in advance for your help.

I don't see VARCHAR2 in list of supported types here odbc_fdw.

Thank you for the information.
I couldn't define it with VARCHAR, so I tried with CHAR instead,
but the result was the same.
CREATE TABLE ssss.TEST_TBL2
(
    DATA_ID                        CHAR(8),
    NAME1                          CHAR(10),
    NAME2                          CHAR(50),
    UPDATE_D                       DATE
)

CREATE FOREIGN TABLE
  odbc_zzzz_test_tbl22 (
    DATA_ID text,
    NAME1 text,
    NAME2 text,
    UPDATE_D date
  )
  SERVER odbc_zzzz
  OPTIONS (
    sql_query 'select DATA_ID,NAME1,NAME2,UPDATE_D from ssss.TEST_TBL2',
    sql_count 'select count(DATA_ID) from ssss.TEST_TBL2'
  );


postgres=#     select count(*) from odbc_zzzz_test_tbl22;
 count
-------
     2
(1 row)


postgres=#     select * from odbc_zzzz_test_tbl22;
 data_id | name1 | name2 | update_d
---------+-------+-------+----------
 #       |       |       |
 #       |       |       |
(2 rows)


Is there really a problem with using Windows in the first place?
**Unfortunately, however, this is a mandatory requirement and cannot be changed.
